# How to wrap text around a floated div as it doesn't work if text is too short?

Tags: html, css

The part of this code that's acting up is the text where it says TEXT HERE. If this line of text is long enough, it wraps nicely around `<div class="pic">`. If it's short, however, it shows up *below* `<div class="pic">`.

How can I get it to wrap around the div no matter how long it is?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.92;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 30px 55px 30px 55px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600;
}

div,
fieldset {
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #5C5C5C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #DEF4FF;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10 15 15 15;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.pic {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="main">
      <h2>asdf</h2>
      <div style="text-align: left; margin: 0px;">
       <div class="pic" style="background: url(http://blabla.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: auto 100%;">
       </div>
       <br />
       TEXT HERE
      </div>
      <fieldset>
       <legend>Ingredients</legend>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="display_ingredient.php?name=Allspice" target="_blank">allspice</a></li>
       </ul>
      </fieldset>
      <br />
      <a target="_blank" href="edit_recipe.php?name=asdf">Edit</a>
      &nbsp;
      <span style="font-size: 20;">
       &#8226;
      </span> &nbsp;
  <a target="_blank" href="delete_recipe.php?name=asdf">Delete</a>
  </span>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aPSqW/

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) from this to show what you mean more clearly.

Comment: Your HTML is a bit of a mess. A fieldset is a form component that should wrap form inputs. It's not merely a styling aid.

Comment: Okay - I made a fiddle, linked at the bottom of the question - http://jsfiddle.net/aPSqW/. Note how the text is showing up below the square div. Try making the line of text longer - it will then wrap nicely around the div.

Comment: @jessica you mean that the text moves to the right of the .pic div? If so, wrap the text in a div or span and float it to the left. Example `<span style="display:block;float:left">TEXT HERE MORE TEXT MORE TEXT</span>` . Also try removing the <br> before the text entirely and use padding / margin instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have been due to some whitespace chars around your text. I suggest some cleanup and validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aPSqW/1/

```
<div class="pic"></div>
T
```

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Ah, you mean that extra line break my php stuck in before the text? I removed it and it worked! Wraps around the div now no matter how long it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line break before the text.